# Fast Marker Clusters Cluster Distance - Folium

Tags: python, mapping, gis, folium, folium-plugins

I am currently using the fast marker cluster function in Folium to aggregate data points on a folium map.

```
marker_cluster_wind = FastMarkerCluster(data=data, callback=callback).add_to(m)
```

I would like to know if there is a method to increase the distance of a cluster so that points further away can cluster together.